# Closest feasible point of a linear program

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I have a standard linear program with inequality and equality constraints:
$$\text{maximize } c^Tx \text{ subject to } Ax \leq 0, Bx = 1, x \geq 0$$

I know the feasible region is non-empty and that there is an optimal solution. Even more, x is a probability vector (equality constraints are the simplex constraint). Now, I have a candidate point that satisfies the equality constraints but violates some of the inquality constraints up to $\epsilon$. In other words, I have a solution $x'$, where $Ax'\leq \epsilon$ and $Bx = 1$. Clearly this is not feasible for the original LP. But, I want to know how far the closest (L1 norm) point to $x'$ that lies the feasible region is.

Does anyone have some intuition about how to reason about this? I'm not sure how to specifically move toward the feasible region is a way that satifies equality constraints and lowers the constraint violation.

Comment: You might look up two-phase simplex method. In one phase you begin with a non-feasible point and pivot etc until getting a feasible point, and in the other phase one starts with that feasible set and pivots in such a way that one keeps to feasible points only until done.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be easy to get a useful bound.
Consider the case with one inequality $\varepsilon x_2 + x_3 \le 0$ (besides $x_1, x_2, x_3 \ge 0$) and one equality $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$.  The only feasible solution is $(1,0,0)$, but $(0,1,0)$ satisfies the inequality up to $\varepsilon$.